# I can not get the one value in Card Visualization

Tags: powerbi, dax

I recently started studying PowerBi and DAX, respectively.

Through what function can I create a measure that returns the film title, instead of id. The title of the movie is in a separate table. I receive the id with this command:

```
(MINX(
     TOPN(1;
         ADDCOLUMNS(
             VALUES('All sessions'[Movie]);
             "Frequency";
             CALCULATE(COUNT('All sessions'[Movie])));
         [Frequency];0);
    'All sessions'[Movie])
```

The column `'All sessions'[Movie]` shows a list of sessions where the movie id is substituted. The name of the films is stored in the `'Movie List'[Movies]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your measure as a variable and use `LOOKUPVALUE` to return the movie title:

```
Title = 
VAR movie_id =
(MINX(
     TOPN(1;
         ADDCOLUMNS(
             VALUES('All sessions'[Movie]);
             "Frequency";
             CALCULATE(COUNT('All sessions'[Movie])));
         [Frequency];0);
    'All sessions'[Movie])
RETURN
LOOKUPVALUE('Movie List'[Movies], 'Movie List'[id], movie_id)
```

Assuming that the id column is called `'Movie List'[id]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! your result helped me to solve the problem.